# Python: convert a list of tuples into a flat list

Tags: python

How would you code for the following outcome?

```
tuple_list = [('a', 1), ('b', 3), ('c', 2), ...]
def flatten_tuple(tuple_list):
    magic_happens here
    return flat_list
flat_list = ['a', 1, 'b', 3, 'c', 2, ...]
```

It's a simple problem to solve this way:

```
def flatten_tuple(tuple_list):
    flat_list = []
    for a, b in tuple_list:
        flat_list.append(a)
        flat_list.append(b)
    return flat_list
```

Am I missing something which can flatten the tuple list without iterating over the list itself?

Comment: You mean like a builtin function?

Comment: Apologies for asking a duplicate question. My search efforts were obviously inadequate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can flatten it using list comprehension like this

```
tuple_list = [('a', 1), ('b', 3), ('c', 2)]
def flatten_tuple(tuple_list):
    #Method 1
    #import itertools
    #return [item for item in itertools.chain.from_iterable(tuple_list)]

    #Method 2
    return [item for tempList in tuple_list for item in tempList]

print flatten_tuple(tuple_list)
```

Or from this excellent answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/952952/1903116 (**Note** works Only in Python 2)

```
tuple_list = [('a', 1), ('b', 3), ('c', 2)]
def flatten_tuple(tuple_list):
    return list(reduce(lambda x,y: x + y, tuple_list))

print flatten_tuple(tuple_list)
```

Comment: Might want to add that the last solution works only in Python 2.x.

Answer (score 2):

Use `itertools.chain`:

```
from itertools import chain

tuple_list = [('a', 1), ('b', 3), ('c', 2)]

list(chain.from_iterable(tuple_list))
Out[5]: ['a', 1, 'b', 3, 'c', 2]
```

Or a nested list comprehension:

```
[elem for sub in tuple_list for elem in sub]
Out[6]: ['a', 1, 'b', 3, 'c', 2]
```